# How many unique primes?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, integer

One way to represent a natural number is by multiplying exponents of prime numbers.  For example, 6 can be represented by 2^1*3^1, and 50 can be represented by 2^1*5^2 (where ^ indicates exponention).  The number of primes in this representation can help determine whether it is shorter to use this method of representation, compared to other methods.  But because I don't want to calculate these by hand, I need a program to do it for me.  However, because I'll have to remember the program until I get home, it needs to be as short as possible.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function to determine how many distinct primes there are in this representation of a number.

### Input:

An integer n such that 1 < n < 10^12, taken by any normal method.

### Output:

The number of distinct primes that are required to represent the input, as outlined in the introduction.

### Test Cases:

```
24      -> 2 (2^3*3^1)
126     -> 3 (2^1*3^2*7^1)
1538493 -> 4 (3^1*11^1*23^1*2027^1)
123456  -> 3 (2^6*3^1*643^1)
```

This is [OEIS A001221](https://oeis.org/A001221).

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: So many prime questions recently! I love it.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why they downvoted?  I would love to fix any issues.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91420/59487)

Comment: The reason behind the downvote might be its triviality. As far as I could see, there are 3 situations when it comes to golfing languages : 1. built-in 2. chain of two built-ins 3. chain of 3 built-ins (I personally have three 2-byte answers); I don't know if that is a solid reason for a downvote, but it is a possible cause

Comment: Could be, but I would appreciate if one of the three downvoters would have commented telling me that.  While it *is* trivial in golfing languages, there are a few interesting solutions in non golfing languages, which are the ones I wanted to see when I posted this challenge.  After all, there are many challenges on the site which are trivial for golflangs, but produce interesting non-golflang solutions.

Comment: It would beneficial to include a prime in the test cases. Also, some languages/approaches are hard to test for large numbers. A few smaller test cases would be nice.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the highest possible result given the input range is `12`.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo*

```
YFz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9Kt6v9/QyMA)

```
YF         Exponents of prime factors
  z        Number of nonzeros
```

Original answer:

```
Yfun
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzKtNO//f0MjAA)

A ver`Yfun` answer.

```
          (Implicit input)
Yf         Prime factorization
  u        Unique
   n       Numel
           (Implicit output)
```

Comment: Why fun? -- ;-)

Comment: Crossed out 4 is still regular 4

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

<sup>another pretty boring answer...</sup>

```
fg
```

A full program accepting a numeric input and printing the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Lf3/f0NTYwsTS2MA)**

#### How?

```
fg - implicitly take input
f  - get the prime factors with no duplicates
 g - get the length
   - implicit print
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 7 bytes

```
PrimeNu
```

Yup, there's a built-in.

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Length@*FactorInteger
```

The long way around.

Comment: What's the reason for the asterisk? Isn't `Length@FactorInteger` the same?

Comment: `Length@*FactorInteger` produces a pure function: the composition of `Length` and `FactorInteger`. I can define `fun=Length@*FactorInteger` and then call `fun[1001]`. On the other hand, `Length@FactorInteger` would mean `Length[FactorInteger]` and evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

<sup>Yet another pretty boring answer... --- J. Allan</sup>

```
ḋl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO7pz//w1NjS1MLI0B)

- `ḋ` - Prime factorization as **[prime, exponent]** pairs.
- `l` - Length.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 33

- 1 byte saved thanks to @Dennis

```bash
factor|grep -Po ' \d+'|uniq|wc -l
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYGSiYGKmYGgExKbGFiaWxkC2sYmpmbVCSj6XAhCkJmfkK6jAtdQo/E9LTC7JL6pJL0otUNANyFdQV4hJ0VavKc3LLKwpT1bQzfmfkp@X@h8A).

#### Explanation

```bash
factor|                            # Split input into prime factors
       grep -Po ' \d+'|            # group factors onto lines
                       uniq|       # remove duplicates
                            wc -l  # count the lines
```

Comment: `grep -Po ' \d+'` saves a byte over `tr \  \\n|sed 1d`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `grep -Po '( \d+)\1*'` fails for input **46**.

Comment: @Dennis thanks - I fixed it using your original suggestion

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 56 bytes

```py
f=lambda n,p=2,k=1:n/p and[f(n,p+1),k+f(n/p,p,0)][n%p<1]
```

Comment: Is this a port of Dennis' answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104591/53748) perchance?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, modified to count unique prime factors instead.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
&`(?!(11+)\1+$)(11+)$(?<=^\2+)
```

Input is in unary.

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for golfing of 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/B@Tos2lovVfLUHDXlHD0FBbM8ZQW0UTzFLRsLexjYsx0tb8/9/QyAwA) (includes decimal-to-unary converter)

#### How it works

Since the program consists of a single regex with the `&` modifier, Retina simply counts the amount of *overlapping* matches. The input is assumed to consist of **n** repetitions of **1** and nothing else.

The negative lookahead

```
(?!(11+)\1+$)
```

matches at locations between **1**'s that are *not* followed by two or more **1**'s (`11+`), followed by one or more repetitions of the same amount of **1**'s (`\1+`), followed by the end of input (`$`).

Any composite number **ab** with **a, b > 1** can be written as **b** repetitions of **a** repetitions of **1**, so the lookahead matches only locations followed by **p** repetitions of **1**, where **p = 1** or **p** is prime.

The regex

```
(11+)$
```

makes sure **p > 1** by requiring at least two **1**'s (`11+`) and stores the tail of **1**'s in the second capture group (`\2`).

Finally, the positive lookbehind

```
(?<=^\2+)
```

verifies that the entire input consists of **kp** occurrences (**k ≥ 1**) of **1**, verifying that **p** divides the input.

Thus, each match corresponds to a unique prime divisor **p**.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

<sup>a pretty boring answer...</sup>

```
ÆFL
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a number

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5vP////DU2NLUwsjQE)**

#### How?

```
ÆFL - Link: number, n
ÆF  - prime factorisation as a list of prime, exponent pairs
  L - length
```

Comment: How did you miss `Æv`?

Comment: It was easy - I've never had a use for it and didn't search the list on the wiki.

Comment: How do you type jelly characters without atoms list and quicks list?

Comment: 1. `Æ` is alt code 0198. 2. You can set up a keyboard  (I have not). 3. The code page.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for 2 bytes off!*

```
{mF,}
```

Anonymous block (function) that expects the input number on the stack and replaces it by the output number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/OtdNp/Z/XcF/IxMA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/OtdNp/a/asH/aCMTBUMjMwVDU2MLE0tjINvYxNQsFgA).

#### Explanation

```
{   }   e# Define block
 mF     e# List of (prime, exponent) pairs
   ,    e# Length
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
ml
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/Pzfn/39DU2MLE0tjAA)

The two built-ins are right next to each other in the documentation lol.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

<sup>Yet another pretty boring answer... --- J. Allan</sup>

```
Æv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9n///8NTY0tTCyNAQ)

A built-in.

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
/o
\i@/Dcd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00HfJTnl/39DU2MLE0tjAA)

#### Explanation

```
/o
\i@/...
```

This is just the standard framework for linear arithmetic-heavy programs that need decimal I/O. The actual program itself is then just:

```
Dcd
```

Which does:

```
D    Deduplicate prime factors. Does what it sounds like: for every p^k which
     is a divisor n, this divides n by p^(k-1).
c    Push the individual prime factors of n. Since we've deduplicated them
     first, the number of factors is equal to the value we're looking for.
d    Push the stack depth, i.e. the number of unique prime factors.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript 45 bytes

*For @SEJPM request an explanation : 
what im doing here is this- im going from 2 - n (which changes, and eventually will be the biggest prime factor)- now if the current number divide n i want to count it only once(even though it can be a factor of 2*2*2*3 - 2 is counted once)- so the "j" comes to the picture, when j is not specified in the call of the funcion - j will receive the value of "undefined" , and when n%i == 0 then i call the function with j=1 in the next call) - and then i only add 1 when j equals undefined which is !j + Function(n/i,i,(j=1 or just 1)). i dont change i in this matter becuase it may still be divisible by i again(2*2*3) but then j will equal 1 and it will not count as a factor.
hope i explained it well enough.

```js
P=(n,i=2,j)=>i>n?0:n%i?P(n,i+1):!j+P(n/i,i,1)

console.log(P(1538493)==4);
console.log(P(24)==2);
console.log(P(126)==3);
console.log(P(123456)==3);
```

if the last prime is very big than it will have max call stack- if its an issue i can make an iterative one

Comment: Would you mind writing an explanation for this answer? It seems to use an usual approach from the rest of the answers.

Comment: @SEJPM i added some explanation there

Comment: FYI we may assume infinite call stacks / infinite resources for the majority of code-golf challenges (basically unless the question states otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
ḋdl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7pSc//8NjYxNTM3@RwEA)

#### Explanation

```
ḋ      Prime decomposition
 d     Remove duplicates
  l    Length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

*1 byte removed thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

```python
lambda n:sum(n%k<all(k%j for j in range(2,k))for k in range(2,n+1))
```

This times out for the largest test cases. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyNPNdsmMSdHI1s1SyEtv0ghSyEzT6EoMS89VcNIJ1tTEySWjSyWp22oqfm/oCgzr0QjTcPQyAzIAwA)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyNPNdsmMSdHI1s1SyEtv0ghSyEzT6EoMS89VcNIJ1tTEySWjSyWp22oqfm/oCgzr0QjTcPQyAzIAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
l{P
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=24%0A126%0A1538493%0A123456&debug=0)

Length (`l`) of set (`{`) of prime factors (`P`) of the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
Lup
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/36e04P///4amxhYmlsYA)

#### Explanation

```
  p  -- prime factors
 u   -- unique elements
L    -- length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

<sup>Yet another pretty boring answer... --- J. Allan</sup>

```
yl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/78y5/9/QwsDAA)

The first character can be replaced by `w`.

Comment: That's enough, dude... :P

Comment: @icrieverytim I promise this is my last ***golfing**-language* answer (I only have 4 :P)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 3 bytes

```
P}l
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=P%7Dl&input=180&warnings=0&hex=0)

Answer (score 2):

## R + numbers, <s>30</s> 14 bytes

*16 bytes removed thanks to @Giuseppe*

```
numbers::omega
```

Also, here is the [Try it online!!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@vNDcptajYyio/NzU98X@ahqGR5n8A) link per @Giuseppe.

Comment: You may omit the `f=function(x)` and the `(x)` as `numbers::omega` is a function already. However, as `numbers` is not standard for R, you should make your answer "R + numbers". Also, you should include a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@vNDcptajYyio/NzU98X@ahqGR5n8A "R – Try It Online"). Still, +1, very nice.

Comment: @Giuseppe, you are too nice. Thanks for your help. BTW, in addition to some of your insightful answers, I checked out [Tips for golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4024/52987), as you suggested.  There are some real gems there.  Anywho, I will update my answer with your recommendations.  Also, your `MATL` solution is very nice (+1 yesterday).

Comment: NP, feel free to ping me in chat or comment on an answer of mine if you have questions.

Comment: @Giuseppe is there a meta consensus on needing to explicitly state "R + numbers"? It seems like if we state the additional package then we should be able to save the bytes of explicitly calling it with `numbers::`. Otherwise, to me it's the same as using an `import` in any other language.

Comment: (scrolls down and sees a python example of this...) I guess I'm wondering about a broader meta consensus, then. It just sort of seems silly to me.

Comment: @BLT yeah, something like [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9279/67312). I do think it's fair since you have to assume that a package like `numbers` is installed on the system at the very least.

Comment: @BLT I agree with Giuseppe. Otherwise the code isn't self contained (IMO it feels sneaky if you don't). Also, I'm not sure about how other languages work, but with R as long as the package is installed, `library` or `require` (the analogue of `import`) isn't necessary.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thank you, that link is perfect. @JosephWood That's true, but you still have to invoke the library with `foo::`, which costs a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 3 bytes

```
mF,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P8/103n////hkbGJqZmAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
â èj
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4iDoag==&input=OA==)

Get the divisors (`â`) and count (`è`) the primes (`j`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 58 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Laikoni*

```hs
f n=sum[1|x<-[2..n],gcd x n>1,all((>)2.gcd x)[2..x-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwFEX3fsUbHBLQQLSFVlTo0KFzR3EINWoweUqSFgv997SKd7lw7uUMwo1S66DMPFkPj4/z0rAbvpWd0Ej0pJf@antHQwdYupep@XcpkjplDJu4f7awAFY8FloTUtGUbYiu@5LwpglGKCyhnQ6wRfxdUCSwa3c6W4U@6oBYKVqIYFhru@Y53NHTEPgpOx8vGfwA)

**Explanation**

Essentially generates all primes at most as large as `n` and filters them for being a factor of n and then takes the length of the result.

```hs
f n=                                                   -- main function
    sum[                                             ] -- output the length of the list
        1|x<-[2..n],                                   -- consider all potential primes <=n
                                                       -- and insert 1 into the list if predicates are satisfied
                    gcd x n>1,                         -- which are a factor of n
                              all(          )[2..x-1]  -- and for which all smaller numbers satisfy
                                  (>)2.                -- 2 being larger than
                                       gcd x           -- the gcd of x with the current smaller number
```

Comment: You can use `sum[1|x<- ... ]` instead of `length`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 5 bytes

I don't know why it is called nu in Mathematica but omega in Pari/GP.

```
omega
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D8/NzU98X9iQUFOpUaegq6dQkFRZl6JApCtBOIpKaRp5Glq6ihEG5noKBgamQEJU2MLE0tjEM/YxNQsVvM/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 28 bytes

```
len(unique(primefactors(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8nNU@jNC@zsDRVo6AoMzc1LTG5JL@oWCNPU1Pz////hiYA)

*This is a very literal solution*

Comment: I was looking at this and going *"Hey, wait a minute, this is a snippet!"* And then I see... is this supposed to be a non-esoteric language with implicit IO?!

Comment: @icrieverytim Congratulations, you have discovered one of the main reasons this language exists.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>63</s>  55 bytes

<sup>A much more interesting answer...</sup>

-8 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) (use an argument with a default for the post-adjustment of the result of primes from `0` to `1` -- much better than a wrapping lambda!!)

```python
f=lambda n,o=1:sum(n%i+f(i,0)<1for i in range(2,n))or o
```

A recursive function taking a positive integer, `n`, and returning a positive integer, the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmxCoAgEIDhuZ7ilsAjhxJapB7GSOugTjEbenrLpqYf/i/cafOscnbTbo55McDST70@r0NwQ60TJDsce@cjEBBDNLxaoSQjvsvnAsme6W@gBtR1FSJxEgUluK@I@QE)** Really inefficient, don't even bother with the other test cases.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcm9DkAwEADgmae4RXIXHaqj8DAVyiXcSdXg6etnMn3Dt19pUXE5h3712zB6EKN90x7nhlJxHZCNpa4JGpGJBaKXeUJnhEhjrfkJSNOR4HfgLLVlsUeWhG8aCJ9E@QY).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks, that is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
≢∪3pco⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdPzc1PfH/o76pzpHqKWl5xepcjzoXPepYZVyQnA8UBSn5D1bDZWSiwMUFYRoamSmAAJxvamxhYmmMJG9sYmoGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 12 bytes

```
{:@$@(__&q:)
```

`q:` is J's prime exponents function, giving it the argument `__` produces a matrix whose first row is all nonzero prime factors and whose 2nd row is their exponents.

We take the shape `$` of that matrix -- rows by columns -- the number of columns is the answer we seek.

`{:` gives us the last item of this two items (num rows, num columns) list, and hence the answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BCsIwEEX3OcWniE2ClmYmjRqoFA/gEdqFNIgbkS7Fs8ekUhuYMPBm/ptHDBNajxqp4tt3m04Ow/blVVSiqFCG1pfY4eMRJiGulwpkMb/9GQRJPWvujZqRIbcgzsgkRPrwxw0f7YkztpBpSxuTPsod1bTOEdvGrTEuG7Szs0eMt/szmTllMFrIUNQqH5Xli@GXEL8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 67 bytes

```java
n->{int c=0,p=1;for(;p<n;)if(n%++p<1)for(c++;n%p<1;n/=p);return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/LboMwELznK0aRkECAW0ISNXWI1GMPVQ9RT1EOLo/IlKwtY1IhxLdTk7aHfc2OdnZqcROx0iXVxddu0t1nI3PkjWhbvAlJGBbAH9paYV25KVng6nb@0RpJl9MZwlza4E4FaneQdVY2rOoot1IReyX7QcL077o0wiqDCtlE8WGQZJFnj5HOEl4p43O9Jx7IyicvDPU@CWYwD0NOnps4PWQ64Ka0nSHkfJz4XdGR4M@n6BlUfsO1p/OA1TpCstq6tEmf1rt0ntL1Zovx/1Xg2Le2vDLVWaadF1v5S69AfIBXeLSMQBEqJrRu@pfWufApCH41x8Uc4/QD)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 56 chars

```
n=>eval(`for(q=2,r=0;q<=n;++q)n%q||(n/=q,r+=!!(n%q--))`)
```

Test:

```js
f=n=>eval(`for(q=2,r=0;q<=n;++q)n%q||(n/=q,r+=!!(n%q--))`)
console.log([24,126,1538493,123456].map(f)=="2,3,4,3")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 + [primefac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac), 50 bytes

```python
from primefac import*
lambda n:len({*primefac(n)})
```

---

## Python 2 + [primefac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac), 52 bytes

```python
from primefac import*
lambda n:len(set(primefac(n)))
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/MVQe)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2,p=1:n/k and(n%k<p%k)+f(n,k+1,p*k*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoMwEAXQdT3F3wwajUhS6UJM75ISgjLtOIibnj5m/Xj6v7ZDfCk5fOPvkyLEcvBWg1tkYkRJnRCvSmyG3FUcnNWeezYlHycEu8DPFs6/luah5y4XWnomjG9QakGoCXUaU24)

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys

X=int(sys.argv[1])
print X
b=2
a=0

while(b<X or b==X):
        if(X%b == 0):
                a=a+1;
                while(X%b==0):
                        X=X/b;
                b=b+1;
        else:
                b=b+1;

print a;
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Could you specify language and bytecount?

Comment: Looks like Python 2.