# Primes in the prime factorisation

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, integer

I saw [another prime challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144633/how-many-unique-primes) coming by in PPCG, and I do love me some primes. Then I misread the introductory text, and wondered what the creative brains here had come up with.

It turns out the question posed was trivial, but I wonder if the same is true of the question I (mis)read:

---

\$6\$ can be represented by \$2^1\times3^1\$, and \$50\$ can be represented by \$2^1\times5^2\$.

### Your task:

Write a program or function to determine how many distinct primes there are in this *representation* of a number.

### Input:

An integer \$n\$ such that \$1 < n < 10^{12}\$, taken by any normal method.

### Output:

The number of distinct primes that are required to *represent the unique prime factors* of \$n\$.

### Test cases:

```
Input      Factorisation      Unique primes in factorisation representation
24         2^3*3^1            2 (2, 3)
126        2^1*3^2*7^1        3 (2, 3, 7)
8          2^3                2 (2, 3)
64         2^6                1 (2) (6 doesn't get factorised further)
72         2^3*3^2            2 (2, 3)
8640       2^6*3^3*5^1        3 (2, 3, 5)
317011968  2^11*3^5*7^2*13^1  6 (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
27         3^3                1 (3)
```

This is not an OEIS sequence.

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: What is the expected result for `64`? Is it `2 (2,3)` (as 6 can be represented as 2*3) or `1 (2)` (ignore the 6)?

Comment: for `64` the expected result is 1 (2). I like the idea of doing it recursively, but that's not the way I read the original question. I thought `8640` was a suitable test case, but should have been more explicit - thanks.

Comment: You claim this is not an OEIS sequence. Is it not A001221, the values of the (small) omega function?

Comment: A001221 is similar, but starts to diverge at terms 8 and 9 (here 2, A001221 1) because of the inclusion of the exponent as prime in this exercise.

Comment: Ah, I see. Write down the prime factorisation, then see how many different 
 primes I wrote (regardless of the role they played). I wonder what happens if you go a step further and factorise the exponent...

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
Count[Union@@FactorInteger@#,_?PrimeQ]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zm/NK8kOjQvMz/PwcEtMbkkv8gzryQ1PbXIQVkn3j6gKDM3NTBW7T@QkVei4JAebWxobmBoaGlmEfv/PwA)

thanks to Martin Ender (-11 bytes)

Comment: `Cases` turns out to be shorter than `Select` (-4 bytes): `Tr[1^Union@Cases[FactorInteger@#,_?PrimeQ,2]]&` (passes all test cases on a fresh kernel)

Comment: How about `Count[Union@@FactorInteger@#,_?PrimeQ]&`? (Haven't checked all test cases.)

Comment: @MartinEnder seems like it should work. Passes all test cases too.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆFFQÆPS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5tb4OG2gOD///8bG5obGBpamlkAAA)** or **[Check out the test Suite.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5tb4OG2gOD/h9sfNa1x//8/2shER8HQyExHwUJHwdwISJmZGOgoGBuaGxgaWppZxAIA)**

### How?

```
ÆFFQÆPS   ~ Full program.

ÆF        ~ Prime factorization as [prime, exponent] pairs.
  F       ~ Flatten.
   Q      ~ Deduplicate.
    ÆP    ~ For each, check if it is prime. 1 if True, 0 if False.
      S   ~ Sum.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
ÓsfìÙpO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8OTitMNrDs8s8P//38LMxAAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ó        # push the prime factor exponents of the input
 sfì     # prepend the prime factors of the input
    Ù    # remove duplicates
     p   # check each if it is prime
      O  # sum
```

Comment: -1 byte by using `€pO` after merging the prime factors and exponents: [`ÓsfìÙ€pO`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8OTitMNrDs981LSmwP//fwszEwMA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Thanks! Actually saves 2 since `€` isn't needed.

Comment: Ah, of course.. Wow, not sure how I missed that, haha xD

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) + [numbers](https://cran.r-project.org/package=numbers), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```r
function(n)sum(isPrime(unique(unlist(rle(primeFactors(n))))))
library(numbers)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7DcAgDAX7TPIYIUXa1FkBEEiWwCQ2LjK987nmpNOJ182rcZ40GBzUOkgPoV5gTJd9aqQT0grOr@8xzyH6zj9LoyRRbrD1VESDV6zBHw)

Similar to Giuseppe (using `numbers` package and `rle`) but no assignments.

Comment: Nice to see a golf in R. Feel free to put your answer up in the [language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r) thread.

Comment: Thank you @Razetime. I don't have enough reputation to edit the community wiki post, but you may feel free to add the entry for me!

Comment: Note that you don't need to include the code that gives a name to your function in the byte-count (unless this is required for the function to run), so you can make it 1-byte shorter: [Try it](https://tio.run/##RYu5DYAwDADXcUYgEi01K0AUS5YSB/zMbwgN11xzJ4FroHMxGgyc1Duw97OK5ky6C/UKznT7VCM1kFb/5JrBdhQbou/@EQhLigc).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @DominicvanEssen.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
&YFhuZpz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy3SLaM0qqDq/39jQ3MDQ0NLMwsA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
ḋ_uṗ¦Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO7vjShzunH1p2bvH//8aG5gaGhpZmFgA)

---

- `ḋ`  computes the prime factorization, as **[prime, exponent]** pairs.
- `_` flattens the list.
- `u` removes duplicate elements.
- `ṗ¦` maps through the elements and returns **1** if a prime is found, **0** otherwise.
- `Σ` sums the list.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (13 bytes)

```
{mFe__&:mp1b}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25%7B~%5C%0A%0A%7BmFe__%26%3Amp1b%7D%0A%0A~%3D%7D%2F&input=24%202%0A126%203%0A8%202%0A72%202%0A8640%203%0A317011968%206%0A27%201)

This is pretty straightforward: get primes with multiplicities, reduce to distinct values, filter primes, count.

Sadly [Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) pointed out some cases which weren't handled by the mildly interesting trick in my original answer, although he did also provide a 1-byte saving by observing that since `mp` gives `0` or `1` it can be mapped rather than filtered.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

```
ä{UpΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr///CS6tCCc4v//zc2NDcwNLQ0swAA)

Comment: 5 bytes: [`ä{UpΣ`](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr///CS6tCCc4v//zc2NDcwNLQ0swAA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks! I was looking for that built-in but wasn't able to find it..

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode) + `dfns`](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
{≢∪⍵/⍨1pco⍵}∘∊2pco⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVOdI9ZS0vGJ1rupHnYsedax61LtV/1HvCsOC5Hwgs/ZRx4xHHV1GIF7Xov9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qmwg0JTjIGUiGeHgG/09TMORKUzACYmMgNgFiQxMA)

-6 bytes from Adám.

### Explanation

```apl
{≢∪⍵/⍨1pco⍵}∘∊2pco⊢ ⊢ → input
                2pco  prime factors and exponents as matrix
{            }∘∊      flatten and use as right arg for:
    ⍵/⍨              filter out values in arg
        1pco⍵         which aren't prime
 ≢∪                   count the unique values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
w♂i╔♂pΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/80cymzEdTpwCpgnOL//83NjQ3MDS0NLMAAA)

Explanation:

```
w♂i╔♂pΣ
w        factor into [prime, exponent] pairs
 ♂i      flatten to 1D list
   ╔     unique elements
    ♂p   for each element: 1 if prime else 0
      Σ  sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk),  <s>11</s>  10 bytes

```
#ṗuS+omLgp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nhzumlwdr5uT7pBf///zc2NDcwNLQ0swAA)

---

**EDIT:** Saved 1 byte thanks to [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb).

Comment: `#ṗuS+omLgp` saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>142</s> <s>135</s> 119 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=2:n-1and(n%d and f(n,d+1)or[d]+f(n/d))or[]
p=f(input())
print sum(f(n)==[n]for n in set(p+map(p.count,p)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BCoMwEETvfsUiFLKYtiYVtUK@RDxYozRQN0EjtF9v1/a0M8ODmQ2f@PSk98HbEQykabpP5tXPD9sDSWt0Q2fVkxV0ssAXJsFxptAvre0ydleLh@mSYCbhKGxRICZhcRRh3WbBCBrTUjf5BQgcwTpGEbK5DyJcBr9RlAERd@5ODsYdTKsLCUqXEmoJJetKsyyLXMJNVblS97LumgTg18jL/5sbcJyN73EQx0e4fwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ḋọcdṗˢl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmJiBXA8h5uKP74e7e5JSHO6efXlSupKn0cFdn7cOtE/6jSOT8/x9tZKJjaGSmY6FjZqJjbqRjYWZioGNsaG5gaGhpZqFjZB4LAA)

```
           The output
      l    is the length of
  c        the concatenated
 ọ         list of pairs [value, number of occurrences]
ḋ          from the prime factorization of
           the input
   d       with duplicates removed
    ṗˢ     and non-primes removed.
```

A fun 9-byte version: [`ḋọ{∋∋ṗ}ᶜ¹`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmJiBXA8h5uKP74e7e5JSHO6efXlSupKn0cFdn7cOtE/5DJKofdXQDEVC29uG2OYd2/v8fbWSiY2hkpmOhY2aiY26kY2FmYqBjbGhuYGhoaWahY2QeCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 66 bytes

```ruby
->n{Prime.prime_division(n).flatten.uniq.count{|i|Prime.prime? i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRToMwFIbveYqTeCEljKztKPNCfQXvl80gFNdEC5ZiYoBXtx7QsG7uJO3Vl//Pd47pXr5cde9WD7p/MupdJs30P5fqU7Wq1qEmSfWWWyt10mn1kRR1p20/qMGjH0GNo9uxTXwDf8MOPOIHCt4wCFkMnASUCR@kCLIoO8H8F4whI8H2RM6hcDFLqPDKERSXIEWQQCigrGWrby28SgtVXtjaqFaWUHXGHqUhQcbOgiYNdrVxKzbrBcVGBHmUXtFIScBptqb0Tsw6qDw5p@jMIjpvSSwsWsdAKT6sYJlnz//boxRS@0TmxbEf7NBAtbP70X3XjcXjtW5l5gP9AA)

Comment: [49 bytes by using the builtin functions added to the number classes when prime is imported](https://tio.run/##bZHhSsMwFIX/9ykuCHMtXdlN1nQK6oOMTWqbuIBLapoKsu3VrXdRujp3IP8@zuHLdd3LZ68e@tmj2ZuscXonn2v9oVttTabeSu@lyTqj37PKdsbD5D4wT8d@xRbpDfyGbXjCNwijMJiyFHgcIRNjEAlkSXGG@Q@YQhFHyzMZSuEiQ6kYjRMoLkEkMIapgNrK1tx6eJUeVFl563Qra1Cd81vp4qhgf4pOGuzq4lIs5gNKiwTyJL@ikccRx2KOeCeCDimfnHNyZgmGXxIDS9YpINKjCVaM7Pl/e5Iiap3JstruD/7QgFr59bH/so2ne7X9zIXrfAM "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
k
âUü ml)èj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=awriVfwgbWwp6Go&input=MzE3MDExOTY4)

### Alternative

```
k
â¡x¶X})xj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=awrioXi2WH0peGo&input=MzE3MDExOTY4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
#ṗuṁS:Lgp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nhzumlD3c2Blv5pBf8///f2NDcwNDQ0swCAA)

Slight improvement over Mr. XCoder's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 37 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.625 bytes

```
ǐĊfUæ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBcz0iLCIiLCLHkMSKZlXDpiIsIiIsIjI0XG4xMjZcbjY0XG44XG4zMTcwMTE5NjggICJd)'

Takes the counts of the prime factorization which gives a list of [prime, exponent] for each prime, flattens, uniquifies, finds the primes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 104 bytes

So long, it can be golfed much more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxNDoMgEAXgfU/BckhZCDXYn/QkjYupDikJIFVM8PTUrtTZfZP3nsdsPZZiIPD7043Uzx2BQ//uEV5ZLK3I54ULj3H7tsIaFkfrKULm6UOBSUZuIlZxMQf7nQmMw5QogDXYpWGc1v3/lcdpLYYEBlTN@Sap9J7XPfQh2ahDUNfV3hfZVFLe9GFANavKDw)

```
f(n):=lreduce(lambda([x,y],x+y),map(lambda([x],if primep(x)then 1 else 0),unique(flatten(ifactors(n)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + numbers, 92 bytes

```r
function(n)sum(1|unique((x=c((r=rle(primeFactors(n)))$l,r$v))[isPrime(x)]))
library(numbers)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqhDsIwFAVQv69ATNybgBgKwSwaTxBb0yYvad/gdY@MhH8voM@xlnbnQ0uuYZVFoaxeMHxc5ekR2MYA2Gg54mFS4mUK62L198g@761/kTep179h453sssw22RvqZY5W2RKGI7uEE9sX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
smP_d{+PQlM.gkP
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smP_d%7B%2BPQlM.gkP&input=8640&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=24%0A126%0A8%0A72%0A8640%0A317011968&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## J, 20 bytes

```
3 :'+/1 p:~.,__ q:y'
```

Counted by hand lol, so tell me if this is off.

Any golfing suggestions?

Boring submission: flatten the prime factorization table and count primes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 47 bytes

```
n->#Set(select(isprime,concat(Vec(factor(n)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMgEEWvMqSbCYwQbdBm0VyikE3oQkSLkBoxs@nprf7V@7yXbYnik2uAZ01ivb084@UP7xjjlUv8enJncpZx8w6DdXwWTGNftTkfP0wgVmhl4oZDPwOEnhDsaiaQShM8CHRjoxrqeSK4SzNJuegmlHmP9Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 145 bytes

```
n=>{for(a=[b=l=0],q=n,d=2;q>=2;)q%d?(b&&(a.push(0),l++),d++,b=0):(q/=d,a[l]++,b=1);for(i in a){for(d=1,e=a[i];e%d;d++);e-d||n%e&&l++};return l+1}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 62 bytes

```
group-factors flatten unique values [ prime? ] filter length ;
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU5BTsMwELz7FXOEQ6ImrZLQSsAN9dIL4oQ4WGHTWji2a6-ReAuXXOAjvKK_wY1BcNmZ3R3NzPvnIHu2fjp9Pdxvd3dryL6nEKwPkAn6gN6OTmnyZWSlFSsKUBYv5A1pjJIP4jxKJ30gj8y9GpPsHy9zTICRaXMyZQjnifkt_Q3jGC1LVtYEBDpGMknwx8pnIoeN2O5Sv-DIVMtOCLHGgAsYFAVGXArgI_JQdKfrvbfRFb-Rg5bMZBCNSn54lTom80fMzW7whEFpTtU1mT0fsPlxua1Xyb8UVd3M2M2zyce2zrdmtZjJsmoXVXXVZFHdniH7TFPGbw)